"Process completed with exit code 137" on running pytest on docker composition service in Github Actions
I have created a workflow for Github Actions to automate tests using pytest. When running on GitHub, I get an error.

I have a problem in the form of an error:
Process completed with exit code 137. 

after running in my Github Actions workflow the command:
docker compose -f testing.yaml exec api pytest


The problem occurs only running on GitHub, locally using ACT - everything works fine.

.github/workflows/checks.yml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  // setup envs from secrets


jobs:
  linting-and-formatting:
    name: Linting and Formatting
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: api

    steps:
      - name: Checkout of the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'

      - name: Create and activate virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv .venv
          source .venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements/development.txt

      - name: Check formatting with Black
        run: black --check --diff .

      - name: Linting with Flake8
        run: flake8 .

  testing:
    needs: linting-and-formatting

    name: Testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        - name: Checkout of the repository
          uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - uses: hoverkraft-tech/compose-action@v2.0.1
          with:
            compose-file: "testing.yaml"
        
        - name: Execute tests in the running services
          run: |
            docker compose -f testing.yaml exec api pytest  //Here there is an error 137


I searched on the internet thath could be error associated with OOM.

Do you know some solution for this situation?

I found the problem.
It was not directly related to OOM. After adding:
- name: Display container logs if tests fail
  if: failure()
    run: |
      docker compose -f testing.yaml logs

I got information that the creation of the superuser failed which was an error of incorrectly initialized environment variables. After changing it, the tests passed correctly.
